# React custom hook for MouseEventHandler with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router, next.js

I am trying to create custom hook in typescript/react - below is the one I want to convert into custom hook. I am currentlt just passing `handleClick` to `onClick` in `div` element to detect user click and route to `new_page`.

```
const handleClick: MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {
   console.log('clicked item')
   e.preventDefault()
   router.push({
     pathname: '/new_page',
     query: {} // parameters I want to pass to the `next_page`
   })
}
```

When I want to convert this to custom hook, I want to set `pathname` and `query` as parameter type so I can use the hook for general purpose to handle user click operations.

For example `my_custom_hook` is like this.

```
interface useMouseProps {
  url: string
  query: string | null | undefined
}

export const useMouse = () => {
  console.log('custom hook clicked - I am not sure how to write code here...')

}
```

But I am not sure how to correctly achieve and construct `useMouse` hook and call from the another file so I can dynamically set `onClick` parameter.

Comment: And what do you intend to do with the hook? I mean how will you use it? I'd simply create a wrapper function that accepts `url` and `query`, and returns an event handler which then you can use in whatever div you want. You can keep this wrapper function in a separate file and import it wherever you need. Not sure if this qualifies as your definition of hook, but it surely will do the job.

Comment: What params would the custom hook accept and what would it return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, a custom hook is not needed. Hooks are characterized by using hooks themselves, otherwise a simple function will suffice.

Since you apparently want to pass dynamic parameters to your function, I would write a **factory function** that returns a new event handler like so:

```
// in getClickHandler.ts
// TODO: type this correctly
export default getClickHandler = (pathname = '/new-page', query = {})=>{
  return (e) => {
     console.log('clicked item')
     e.preventDefault()
     router.push({
       pathname,
       query,
     })
  }
}

// usage
import getClickHandler from './getClickHandler';
// in react component
const handleClick = getClickHandler('/new-page', {prop1: "value1"});
```